# Install Windows 10 and Windows XP on the same machine, but two separate hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, ide, ahci

Hi I'm try installing Windows 10 and Windows 10 on a one PC, but two separate discs. One hdd (XP) and ssd (10). Hardware for Windows 10 and Windows XP both comabibility.

Motherboard: Asus P9X79 Pro

Memory: 48gb ram 1866Mhz

CPU: Xeon E5-1620 v2

Hard disc: 1x SSD 256 + 2x HDD 1tb

GPU: GTX 780 TI

Windows XP service pack 2 (this version i have on CD) installing sucessfuly in IDE mode, but after AHCI switch not booting. I try add EFI using this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqq87j2jJZY

Bootloader configuration from EasyBCD:

https://pastebin.com/FSQqgSri

Do somebody install Windows 10 and Windows XP in one PC, but two separate hard drive? I want play games in Windows XP ale switch to Windows 10 to browse internet and others. I don't want virtual machinve becouse it make latency in 3D games.

Comment: **Windows XP has zero support for EFI and GPT.** You are most likely going to run into some serious hardware compatibility issues.  This is especially true since you are running Windows XP SP2.  Windows XP only supports MBR and you will be unable to install it to that SSD.  Your BCD confirms you have installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode, which means, you will be unable to boot into Windows XP in that current configuration.  I am not even saying it is possible, given the hardware you have, is more than likely completely incompatible with Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible (at least to within 99%). Windows XP is too old to run on modem hardware.

The very best you can do is run run XP in a virtual machine inside Windows 10. This will work - I have it running here.

Make sure the host machine is fast with a fast SSD drive.

Comment: I found it:
https://www.win-raid.com/t485f23-How-to-enable-AHCI-RAID-on-x-in-Windows-XP-bit.html
https://www.win-raid.com/t22f45-Guide-Integration-of-Intels-AHCI-RAID-drivers-into-a-Windows-XP-W-k-W-k-CD.html

I try modify installation CD

Comment: I don't want virtual machinve becouse it make latency in 3D games.